# PostgreSQL 12 on Travis-CI taking 5 minutes to startup?

Tags: postgresql, travis-ci

After reading through [this post](https://travis-ci.community/t/test-against-postgres-12/6768) in the Travis-CI forum I've managed to setup PostgreSQL 12. My configuration looks more or less like this ([full `.travis.yml`](https://github.com/zeroplexer/ch.bfh.bti7081.s2020.blue/blob/master/.travis.yml)):

```yaml
language: java
dist: bionic

[...]

services:
  - postgresql

addons:
  postgresql: '12'
  apt:
    packages:
      - postgresql-12
      - postgresql-client-12

before_install:
  - sudo pg_dropcluster --stop 12 main
  - sudo pg_upgradecluster 11 main
  - sudo pg_ctlcluster 12 main restart
  - sudo pg_dropcluster 11 main

env:
  global:
    - PGUSER=postgres
    - PGPORT=5432

[...]
```

But (as also noticed in the forum) **PostgreSQL takes 5 minutes to startup**. This is a real pain for fast CI/CD. [Here](https://travis-ci.com/github/zeroplexer/ch.bfh.bti7081.s2020.blue/jobs/331953770) is a build example.

Does anyone have experience with it?
Sadly, there is no logging output at all. Are those scripts available for public anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to fix it. I pretty much copied the configuration from the default PostgreSQL version installed. Then just `sed` it and restart the server. [here](https://github.com/zeroplexer/ch.bfh.bti7081.s2020.blue/pull/54/commits/eb0e16984ab66185d9d4e91b481a4f6ff076d0e9) is the commit and it looks something like this in `.travis-ci.yaml`:

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - postgresql-12
      - postgresql-client-12

before_install:
  - sudo sed -i 's/port = 5433/port = 5432/' /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf
  - sudo cp /etc/postgresql/{9.3,12}/main/pg_hba.conf
  - sudo pg_ctlcluster 12 main restart
```

Build time reduced from ~ 11 min to just ~ 3 min.

Thing is, I've already done this once before with v10. But didn't remember it exactly, until now. But in case you're wondering, [this](https://github.com/tbmelabs/tbmelabs-authorization-server/blob/master/.travis.yml) was the `.travis-ci.yml` for PostgreSQL v10.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr Just delete the PostgreSQL service.

So delete this:

```
services:
  - postgresql
```

and delete the rest of the things from that post in Travis community.

I'm not sure how that problem is arising, but you can get a fix here: https://travis-ci.org/github/psycopg/psycopg3/jobs/685827089

Just press View config and you can see how PostgreSQL 12 is setup in 3 seconds. But if you're lazy:

```
    - python: 3.8
      addons:
        postgresql: '12'
        apt:
          packages:
            - postgresql-12
            - postgresql-client-12
      env:
        - TOXENV=py38
        - PGVER=12
        - PSYCOPG3_IMPL=c
        - PGPORT=5433
```

I followed that support post, too. I don't know why it hangs for 5 minutes. I looked into the Travis CI build repo, but the only command executed was `sudo systemctl postgresql start`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. it seems to be a bug maybe. I am on travis-ci [.com] not [.org]. and if I remove the service part it doens't start at all: https://travis-ci.com/github/zeroplexer/ch.bfh.bti7081.s2020.blue/jobs/335594163/config

Comment: @bbortt Try using xenial.

Comment: I finally managed to spend some time on it again and I've got it working in a pretty simple way. actually I've done it once before using PostgreSQL v10 and didn't remember it. only little adaptions we're needed. I'll answer it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dist: focal` for Postgres 12+ seems to eliminate the 5 minute delay. Here's an example config for fast startup times for Postgres 9.6-13.

```yaml
jobs:
  include:
    - name: "Postgres 13"
      dist: focal
      addons:
        postgresql: "13"
        apt:
          sources:
            - sourceline: deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main 13
              key_url: https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc
          packages:
            - postgresql-13
    - name: "Postgres 12"
      dist: focal
      addons:
        postgresql: "12"
        apt:
          packages:
            - postgresql-12
      env:
        - PGPORT=5433
    - name: "Postgres 11"
      dist: bionic
      addons:
        postgresql: "11"
    - name: "Postgres 10"
      dist: bionic
      addons:
        postgresql: "10"
    - name: "Postgres 9.6"
      dist: bionic
      addons:
        postgresql: "9.6"
```